# How can I install tree on CentOS cluster?

Tags: centos-7, cluster, tree

How can I install tree program on a CentOS cluster where I do not have sudo privileges?

Comment: You should probably ask the administrator to install it for you

Comment: I searched the web but couldn't find any source code or web site to build it from scratch.

Comment: If you mean the default `tree-1.6.0`, it's one file = 'tree' https://www.dropbox.com/s/qcc30k6j2g50gn5/tree-1.6.0-10.el7.x86_64.tar.gz?dl=0 ..... Use as `./tree`